# How to use sudo -u option?

Tags: sudo, fdisk

I have 2 users, userA and userB. userB needs to run some commands as userA. I have specified these options in `/etc/sudoers` as below:

```
userA ALL=(ALL) ALL
userB ALL=(vinoth) /sbin/fdisk
```

I ran this command as userB:

```
sudo -u userA fdisk -l
```

It asked for the password of userB. Once I entered the password, the command didn't give the fdisk output.

Comment: What did it give? Wasn't there an error message? What user is running the command? Are you trying to have `userB` run `fdisk` as `userA`?

Comment: Hi Terdon, thanks for your time                                                               yes userB trying to run the command fdisk as userA. there was no error message.

Comment: Does userA have the privilege to get fdisk -l output?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. In your configuration you allowed:

   - `userA` to run any command as any user
   - `userB` to run `fdisk` as `vinoth`
2. `fdisk` by default requires `root` privileges to access the devices, you cannot run it as `userA`, ie. you can run, but `fdisk -l` will print no output, which is what you got.
3. Finally `sudo` command is not transitive. When you execute a command from `userB` account using `sudo -u userA <command>`, the `<command>` will be run using `userA` credentials and the fact that `userA` has settings defined in `sudoers` does not apply to this command.

---

## Using `sudo -u`

To allow `userB` to execute command as `userA` you need to put the following into `sudoers`:

```
userB ALL=(userA) /usr/bin/whoami
```

then login to shell as `userB` and execute:

```
$ sudo -u userA whoami
userA
```

But `userA` has permissions to run `whoami` (which it does). It does not for `fdisk`.

---

## Enabling `fdisk` for regular users

`fdisk` itself is not restricted to `root` account, however it requires access to disk devices (stored in `/dev` which are not accessible to regular users). To give user permission to run `fdisk` you can either:

1. Enable `sudo` for the account. Running `sudo fdisk -l` effectively means `fdisk` is run on `root` account.
2. Add the account to `disk` group, which will allow running `fdisk -l` without `sudo`, using account credentials.

Comment: Thanks techraf, its work . Assume that UserA has permission to run fdisk command . in this case how can userB run fdisk as userA

Comment: If UserA had permission to run `fdisk`, then your configuration in the original post would work.

Comment: @ Techraf ,                                                                                                         for userA: i have added the line in /etc/sudoers file as given below                            `userA ALL=ALL`  then only im trying to run the command as userA

Comment: @techraf. thanks for your explanation. now i understood why it wasn't work when i ran the command